# How to grep a word with number of characters stored in a variable

Tags: bash, grep

How do I grep a word in file with specific number of characters, which I have stored in a variable?

```
VAR=8
grep -E '\<[[:alpha:]]{$VAR}\>' file
```

This gives me an error

```
grep: malformed repeat count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var=8
grep -owE "[[:alnum:]]{$var}" file
```

- Use double quotes for variable expansion
- Use `-w` for matching full word
- Use `-E` for extended regex
- Optionally use `-o` to print only matching text
- Better to use lowercase variable in shell to avoid conflict with shell env variables